# What is a poset?

Tags: terminology

I know the standard definition, but are there any alternative definitions? In particular, I distinctly remember seeing a remark that the definition given by John Kelley in his classic text on General Topology was non-standard.

Comment: Just to clarify, which do you refer to as the "standard definition", and do you still have Kelley's text on hand?

Comment: Kelley, p. 13:  "An ordering (partial ordering, quasi-ordering) is a transitive relation".

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks. That, in reality, is EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So a poset is a reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive relation:

$x\leq x$    => Reflexive

$x\leq y\land y\leq x\;\Rightarrow\;x=y$ =>  Antisymmetric

$x\leq y\land y\leq z\;\Rightarrow\;x\leq z$ => Transitive

...for $x,y,z\in M$, whereas the inverse relation still a poset is:

${\displaystyle y\preceq x:\Longleftrightarrow x\leq y}$

This is the fundamental idea and should be the original version (with different variables of course)

Comment: That may be standard  nowadays, but that is not what Kelley has.